# Reduced groupoid $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, groupoids

I was reading Ozawa's book and in Chapter 5 they discuss $C^* $-algebras of locally compact Hausforff étale groupoids. I have a question regarding the reduced $C^* $-algebra construction.

It is first defined by considering the $* $-algebra $C_c(G)$ and endow it with a $C_0(G^{(0)})$-valued inner product defined for $f,g \in C_c(G)$ and $x \in G^{(0)}$ by
$$
\langle f,g \rangle(x) = \sum\limits_{\gamma \in G_x}\overline{f(\gamma)}g(\gamma).
$$
Thus we obtain the Hilbert module $L^2(G)$ completing $C_c(G)$ for this inner product. Now we define the left regular representation $\lambda: C_c(G) \xrightarrow{} B(L^2(G))$ by
$$
\lambda(f)g = f* g, \quad \text{ for } f,g \in C_c(G),
$$
and endow $C_c(G)$ with the norm $\|f\|_\lambda := \|\lambda(f)\|.$ Completing for this norm, we obtain the reduced groupoid $C^* $-algebra, denoted by $C_\lambda^* (G)$.

However, there is a footnote saying that we can consider a Hilbert space instead of module by letting $\mu$ be a regular Borel measure with full support on $G^{(0)}$ and defining an inner product on $C_c(G)$ by
$$
\langle f,g \rangle_\mu := \int_{G^{(0)}} \langle f,g \rangle(x) d\mu,
$$
obtaining the Hilber space $L^2(G,\mu)$ through completion. We can then consider the same regular representation on $B(L^2(G,\mu))$ and complete $C_c(G)$ for the norm $\|f\|_{\lambda,\mu} := \|\lambda(f) \|_{B(L^2(G,\mu))}$ and lets denote this by $C_{\lambda,\mu}^* (G)$.

My question is how do these norms relate.

The first one is
$$
\|f\|_\lambda^2 = \|\lambda(f)\|_{B(L^2(G))}^2 = \sup\limits_{\|g\|_{L^2(G)}=1} \|f * g \|_{L^2(G)}^2 = \sup\limits_{\|g\|_{L^2(G)}=1} \| \langle f * g, f * g \rangle \|_\infty.
$$
while the second,
$$ \| f \|_{\lambda,\mu}^2 = \| \lambda(f) \|_{B(L^2(G,\mu))}^2 = \sup\limits_{\| g \|_{L^2(G,\mu)} = 1} \| f * g \|_{L^2(G,\mu)}^2 = \sup\limits_{\| g \|_{L^2(G,\mu)}=1} \int_{G^{(0)}} \langle f * g, f * g \rangle(x) d\mu . 
$$
We can see that in case 1 the norm is obtained by taking taking the infinity norm of $\langle f* g,f* g \rangle$ but on the second we take the $L^1$ norm of the same function.

Because of this I'm having troubles believing these form the same $C^* $-algebra, did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distinguish the two regular representations, I will write $\lambda$ for the representation of $C_c(G)$ on $\mathbb{B}(L^2(G))$ and $\lambda_\mu$ for the representation of $C_c(G)$ on $\mathbb{B}(L^2(G,\mu))$.

The same footnote mentioned in your post states that there is an isomorphism between the Hilbert spaces $L^2(G,\mu)$ and $L^2(G)\otimes_{C_0(G^{(0)})}L^2(G^{(0)},\mu)$.  In fact, there is a unitary
\begin{align*}
U:L^2(G)\otimes_{C_0(G^{(0)})}L^2(G^{(0)},\mu)\to L^2(G,\mu)
\end{align*}
such that for all $\xi\in C_c(G)\subset L^2(G)$, $\eta\in C_c(G^{(0)})\subset L^2(G^{(0)},\mu)$, and $\gamma\in G$, one has $U(\xi\otimes\eta)(\gamma)=\xi(\gamma)\eta(s(\gamma))$.  Now fix $f\in C_c(G)$. If $\xi\in C_c(G)$, $\eta\in C_c(G^{(0)})$, and $\gamma\in G$, then
\begin{align*}
\left[\lambda_\mu(f)U(\xi\otimes\eta)\right](\gamma)
&=\sum_{\alpha\beta=\gamma}f(\alpha)U(\xi\otimes\eta)(\beta)
\\&=\left[\sum_{\alpha\beta=\gamma}f(\alpha)\xi(\beta)\right]\eta(s(\gamma))
\\&=[\lambda(f)\xi](\gamma)\eta(s(\gamma))
\\&=U([\lambda(f)\xi]\otimes\eta)(\gamma)
\\&=[U(\lambda(f)\otimes1)(\xi\otimes\eta)](\gamma).
\end{align*}
It follows that $\lambda(f)\otimes 1=U^*\lambda_\mu(f)U$, and thus
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda(f)\|_{\mathbb{B}(L^2(G))}
=\|\lambda(f)\otimes 1\|_{\mathbb{B}(L^2(G)\otimes_{C_0(G^{(0)})}L^2(G^{(0)},\mu))}
=\|\lambda_\mu(f)\|_{\mathbb{B}(L^2(G,\mu))}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Omg yes, thank you so much! I see a lot of proofs that use an auxiliary tensor product space to make some deductions like in this case, however, I still don't have an intuition on when to resort to them. By any chance is there any rule of thumb on when to use tensor products as an auxiliary tool?

Comment: You're welcome!  In this example, we were trying to show that a representation on a Hilbert $C^*$-module gave the same norm as a representation on a Hilbert space.  One may hope that this technique would apply in the following scenario:  You have a $*$-algebra $A$, which can be represented both on a Hilbert $B$-module $E$, and a Hilbert $C$-module $F$, and you want to show that the operator norms of these two representations agree.  Try looking at the $*$-homomorphisms $B\to\mathbb{B}_C(F)$ to see if the representation on $E$ looks like an induced representation on $E\otimes_BF$.