# Equality of norms Groupoid $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, groupoids

In the post " [Reduced groupoid $C^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864067/reduced-groupoid-c-algebra) " I discuss two possible ways to construct the reduced groupoid $C^* $-algebra $C_\lambda^* (G)$ of an étale locally compact Hausdorff groupoid $G$.

However, I came across a new one in Aidan Sims' notes " https://www.aidansims.com/files/GroupoidsNotes-2017.pdf ". Here, to each $x \in G^{(0)}$ we associate the left regular representation of $C_c(G)$ on $B(\ell^2(G_x))$ given by $\lambda_x(f)g = (f*g)|_{G_x}$. We thus define the reduced group $C^* $-algebra by the closure of

$$
\left( \bigoplus\limits_{x \in G^{(0)}} \lambda_x \right)(C_c(G)) \subseteq \bigoplus\limits_{x \in G^{(0)}} B(\ell^2(G_x)).
$$

The norm, which for distinction we will call $\| \cdot \|_\oplus$ is given by

$$
\|f\|_\oplus = \sup\limits_{x \in G^{(0)}} \|\lambda_x(f)\| = \sup\limits_{x \in G^{(0)}} \sup\limits_{\|g\|_{\ell^2(G_x)} = 1} \sum\limits_{\gamma \in G_x} |f*g(\gamma)|^2,
$$

On the other hand, if we use the Hilbert Modules approach (can be found here  " [Reduced groupoid $C^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864067/reduced-groupoid-c-algebra) ") the norm is

$$
\|f\|_\lambda = \sup\limits_{x \in G^{(0)}} \sup\limits_{\|g\|_{L^2(G)} = 1} \sum\limits_{\gamma \in G_x} |f*g(\gamma)|^2
$$

The goal of course, is to show that the norms are equal, and this almost proves it, however we need to compare $\|g\|_{L^2(G)} = 1$ with $\|g\|_{\ell^2(G_x)} = 1$.

In Aidan's notes its written that it "is a fairly straightforward exercise, if you are familiar with Hilbert modules" (p. 23). I am very interested in knowing what he means by this since my knowledge of Hilbert Modules is rudimentary and I feel it would be a good way to avoid the technical detail I was having above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing $\|f\|_\lambda=\|f\|_\oplus$ is handled similarly to your previous post.  In this situation, rather than considering a regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $G^{(0)}$ with full support, we consider the counting measure on $G^{(0)}$. There is still a unitary $U:L^2(G)\otimes_{C_0(G^{(0)})}\ell^2(G^{(0)})\to\oplus_{x\in G^{(0)}}\ell^2(G_x)$ such that for all $\xi\in C_c(G)$, $\eta\in\ell^2(G^{(0)})$, and $\gamma\in G$, we have
\begin{align*}
U(\xi\otimes\eta)(\gamma)=\xi(\gamma)\eta(s(\gamma)).
\end{align*}
Moreover, the same calculation as in the answer to your previous post shows us that for all $f\in C_c(G)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda(f)\otimes1=U^*\lambda_\oplus(f)U, 
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_\oplus=\oplus_{x\in G^{(0)}}\lambda_x$. Hence $\|\lambda(f)\otimes1\|=\|f\|_\oplus$. Since the representation of $C_0(G^{(0)})$ on $\ell^2(G^{(0)})$ is faithful, the $*$-homomorphism $\mathbb{B}(L^2(G))\to\mathbb{B}(L^2(G)\otimes_{C_0(G^{(0)})}\ell^2(G^{(0)}))$ given by  $T\mapsto T\otimes 1$ is injective. Hence $\|f\|_\lambda=\|\lambda(f)\otimes1\|$, and therefore $\|f\|_\lambda=\|f\|_\oplus$.

Comment: It was right in front of me, thank you so much! By any chance do you know what Aidan Sims meant by "is a fairly straightforward exercise, if you are familiar with Hilbert modules"?

Comment: You are very welcome!  I am not certain, but my guess would be that they intended familiarity with tensor products of Hilbert modules.